# Debugging - logging in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging

NEWBIE logger question here:

What's the best way to log output to a development log for debugging purposes?  How do you do it in a way that's quick, simple, effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that I prefer over logging is using [ruby debug](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug). It allows you to put a break point anywhere in your code and inspect all local variables at that point in time. I find it more useful for tracking down bugs in cases where you have no friggin' idea what's going on and just want to look at everything.

Say you had a method like this and the behavior was not what you expected:

```
def my_method(arg)
  # do something with argument
end
```

You could stick a debugger line in there:

```
def my_method(arg)
  debugger
  # do something with argument
end
```

You'll be able to then do things like this to get a better idea of what is going on:

```
p arg
p arg.method
p arg.another_method
p local_var
p local_var.method
```

Answer (score 4):

To log in log/development.log:

```
Rails.logger.debug "Hello!"
```

Or, if you want to create a separate log, you could create a new logger in an initializer (config/initializers):

```
MyLogger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log", "custom.log"))
```

Then, in your app you can call:

```
MyLogger.debug "Hello!"
```